# Controlling a USB relay from LabView?

Tags: relay

I am trying to control a [SainSmart 4 channel 12VDC relay](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-4-channel-12-v-usb-relay-board-module-controller-for-automation-robotics.html) from Labview and having some trouble.  I was hoping to control the module via serial comms but this does not seem to be working. Can anyone suggest an example that I might follow to set this up?

Comment: That's not a USB-serial device.  You need some sort of driver which can talk to an FT-245.  You might be able to write it yourself, or even have labview execute a command line program or link against some custom C code or something.

Answer (score 1):

The relay board uses the FT245RL FTDI chip.  Labview examples for interfacing with FTDI chips can be found at http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/LabVIEW.htm